# extract table rows with XPATH

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I have html code that look like:

```
<TR ALIGN="LEFT">
<TD headers="usdot_number" ><center><font size="-1" face="Arial, Helvetica">1259247</FONT></center></TD>
<TD headers="prefix"><center><font size="-1" face="Arial, Helvetica">MC</FONT></center></TD>
<TD headers="docket_number" ><center><font size="-1" face="Arial, Helvetica">493001</FONT></center></TD>
<TD headers="legal_name" ><center><font size="-1" face="Arial, Helvetica"> E L ZAPATA TRANS INC</FONT></center></TD>
<TD headers="dba_name">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD headers="city" ><center><font size="-1" face="Arial, Helvetica">SPRING VALLEY</FONT></center></TD>
<TD headers="state" ><center><font size="-1" face="Arial, Helvetica">CA</FONT></center></TD>
<td headers="view_details"><center><font size="-1" face="Arial, Helvetica">
<BR>
<FORM ACTION="pkg_carrquery.prc_getdetail" METHOD="POST">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="pv_apcant_id" VALUE="406294">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="pv_vpath" VALUE="LIVIEW">
<input type="submit" value="HTML" onClick="">
</FORM>
</font></center></td>
<td headers="view_details"><center><font size="-1" face="Arial, Helvetica">
<BR>
<FORM ACTION="http://li-public.fmcsa.dot.gov/reports/rwservlet" METHOD="POST" name="reportForm" onSubmit="submitReportRequest(this.rptSummit,this)">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="hidden_run_parameters" VALUE="lirpt">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="report" VALUE="/u01/oracle/lirpts/li_carrier.rdf">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_apcant" VALUE="406294">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="p_user" VALUE="WEBLIVIEW">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Report" name="rptSummit">
</FORM>
</td>
```

I want to extract some values of each TD (usdot_number, docket_number, dba_name and legal_name) and the pv_apcant_id value (406294) from the example. I tried to begin with:

```
('//TABLE/TD headers/')
```

But didn't work. I don't know how deal with the `TD[space]headers=value/` expression. Anyone can please help me with a suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access attribute in XPaths, you need to use the `@` character.

Here is how you can get the `usdot_number` text:

```
response.xpath("//td[@headers = 'usdot_number']/center/font").extract()
```

Here is a sample expression to extract the `pv_apcant_id` value:

```
response.xpath("//input[@name = 'pv_apcant_id']/@value").extract()
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! Last question, how i can adjust my parse function to do the extraction? I tried with:


`def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//table'):
            usdot = sel.xpath("//td[@headers = 'usdot_number']/center/font").extract()`

And not work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @chango not that the inner expression has to start with a `.`: `sel.xpath(".//td[@headers = 'usdot_number']/center/font").extract()`. Hope that helps.